# Number of (atomic) actions to perform a task

Tags: interface, actions, ease-of-use

In all the tools I'm coding, I'm searching the least number of atomic actions to perform a task.

After decades, I came to this [empirical conclusion](https://github.com/josephernest/Yopp#minimalist-ux):

> I noticed that my likelihood/probability to use any tool (all other things being equal) is more or less proportional to:
>
> ```
>    P = 1 / a^2
> ```
>
> where a is the number of required actions/user inputs. If the number of required actions is doubled, the likelihood that I'll use the tool is divided by 4.

This is done on a rather empirical way (details about methodology currently being written), but are there some studies about such a law?

I've read *The human interface* by [Jef Raskin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jef_Raskin) (one of the leaders of the [Macintosh project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macintosh#Naming)) which is quite interesting on this topic, but I'm curious about other references on this topic.

Comment: Are clicks directly related to atomic actions? Otherwise I'm not sure atomic actions are really UX related.

Comment: @RobE I coined this term, not sure it exists in UI, I mean: the smallest unit of action (i.e. a keypress, or could even be a move of the hand keyboard -> to mouse, or mouse -> keyboard). What defines the smallest unit of action may vary among the application.

Comment: Okay, as I was a bit confused by the terms definition on google search. Sounds like really interesting research though!

Answer (score 1):

### References for likelihood of use / clicks:

[Jared M. Spool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jared_Spool) writes about research conducted to test the famous ["Three click rule"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-click_rule) in web design. The link to the article can be found [here](https://articles.uie.com/three_click_rule/).

In this study he concludes that:

> Our analysis showed that there wasn’t any more likelihood of a user quitting after three clicks than after 12 clicks. When we compared the successful tasks to the unsuccessful ones, we found no differences in the distributions of tasks lengths. Hardly anybody gave up after three clicks.

[image]

> According to the Three-Click Rule, most people give up after three clicks. However, in our study, users often kept going, some as many as 25 clicks.

I hope this helps and good luck with your interesting research!